# Splitting list of n elements(size = 2 Bytes,decimal) to 2n elements(size = 1 Byte,hexadecimal)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I have a list of n elements in decimal where each element is two bytes long.

Lets say:

```
x = [9000 , 5000 , 2000 , 400]
```

The idea is to split each element into MSB and LSB and store it in consecutive list elements.

Output should be :

```
y = [23 , 28 , 13 , 88 , 07 , D0 , 01 , 90]
```

Now the basic logic for a signal number operation is clear:

```
x=9000
y_msb = x//256 #Hex Quotient for FF
y_lsb = x%256 #Hex Remainder for FF
```

And store both values in Hex

Output:

```
y_msb=23
y_lsb=28
```

My question is what is the most efficient way to do this operation in **Python3 lists of size n.**

Answer (score 1):

With a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and some bit manipulation, you can do that like:

#### Code:

```
data = sum(((d >> 8, d & 0xff) for d in in_data), ())
```

#### Test Code:

```
in_data = [9000 , 5000 , 2000 , 400]
out_data = (0x23, 0x28, 0x13, 0x88, 0x07, 0xD0, 0x01, 0x90)

data = sum(((d >> 8, d & 0xff) for d in in_data), ())
assert data == out_data
```